# How can I make amends for kissing a girl with bad intentions four years ago?

Tags: tawba

I'm 18 years old and I seek advice on a sin I committed few years back and want to do tauba.

I was in around 9th standard and just entered my adulthood (baligh), after iftaar in ramadhan.  In my room, I was sitting with a neighbour's daughter 4 years old and kissed her on her neck three or four times with bad intentions. 
I can still remember it today and I am depressed and embarrassed.  How can I make amends for this?  Is it "[kaffara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidyah_and_Kaffara)"?

Answer (score 1):

During the time of the prophet (saw), a man came to him to ask about the exact same problem. That event is described in the following narration:

> Ibn Mas'ud (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>
> A man kissed a woman. So he came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and
> informed him about it. Then Allah revealed this Ayah: "And perform the
> Salat, between the two ends of the day and in some hours of the night.
> Verily, the good deeds efface the evil deeds (i.e., minor sins)."
> (11:114) The man asked the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) whether this applies
> to him only. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "It applies to all of my
> Ummah."
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].
>
> https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/54

I hope this answers your question.